# Excel: use wildcard in the lookup range

Tags: excel

I have values in columns A, C, and D.

Each cell in column A is either an exact match for a cell in column C, or is a partial match (with the value in column A containing more characters). For example:

```
A                B              C              D

Park value                      Sprint         Type1
Sprint teller                   Call B         Type3
Call centre                     Call A         Type3
Call A centre                   Call centre    Type3
Call B centre                   Park           Type2
```

I want to populate column B with the Type (from column D) that matches. This is what I want to end up with:

```
A                B              C              D

Park value       Type2          Sprint         Type1
Sprint teller    Type1          Call B         Type3
Call centre      Type3          Call A         Type3
Call A centre    Type3          Call centre    Type3
Call B centre    Type3          Park           Type2
```

How can I do this in Excel?

Comment: https://exceljet.net/formula/first-match-in-range-with-wildcard

Comment: @Slai thanks for the start, but =INDEX(C2:C5, MATCH(A2&"*", C2:C5, 0)) doesn't work.

Comment: Essentially the wildcard would need to be in the lookup range (column C), but I can't get that to work.

Comment: oh you want the opposite .. that will be a bit tricky ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This alternative requires a helper column in `E2`:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$6, MATCH($C2 & "*", $A$2:$A$6, 0))
```

and then in `B2`:

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$6, MATCH($A2, $E$2:$E$6, 0))
```

It can probably be done without helper column with array formula.

---

If the range is formatted as table (Insert tab -> Table), [structured references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e) can be used instead:

```
=INDEX([A], MATCH([@C] & "*", [A], 0))
```

and

```
=INDEX([D], MATCH([@A], [E], 0))
```